# Google Sheets: REGEXEXTRACT Formula to remove characters not inside [brackets] but leave , commas?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex, regexextract

I'm trying to create a formula that uses either `=REGEXEXTRACT` or `=REGEXREPLACE` to remove all characters not inside [brackets] but leaving the ,,, commas where they are.

**For example...**

**➜ Text to Regex:**

> Checkbox 1, Checkbox 2, Checkbox 3[checked], Checkbox 4[disabled]

**✔ Expected Result:**

> , , checked, disabled

My broken formula so far is...

```
=REGEXEXTRACT (J2, "\[([A-Za-z]+)\]")
```

**✖ Current Result:**

> checked

---

Does anyone know the correct way to achieve this?

---

### UPDATE

I created this Google Sheet to show the current work:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UEO22NB9O6hvbTQzIa2YlMys1GF7ZBpe8aVzmX7dOnk/edit#gid=0

Comment: ,,,,,,,,, Done.

Comment: It's a part of the Google Font directory I believe. One of my favorite fonts

Comment: Can you please also update the Google Forum Post, to have this answer?

Comment: Done. @JacobJanTuinstra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\w+\s*\d*\[?(\b\S+\b)?\]?(,?)(\s*|$)","$1$2")
```

Comment: that was really close!! I'm having an issue w/ `col b2` from my link, have a look https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UEO22NB9O6hvbTQzIa2YlMys1GF7ZBpe8aVzmX7dOnk/edit#gid=0

Comment: oops! sorry about that!!,,, here's the shareable link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UEO22NB9O6hvbTQzIa2YlMys1GF7ZBpe8aVzmX7dOnk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: did you see the issue? The "Textbox" string in `cell b2` is still showing instead of it being "" (blank).

Comment: I updated the Spreadsheet to be more readable/ editable and also made `B3` and `C3` ARRAYFORMULA's. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UEO22NB9O6hvbTQzIa2YlMys1GF7ZBpe8aVzmX7dOnk/edit?usp=sharing